# Need help in string combinations with repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm stuck in a tricky mathematical combination question which demands the following:

Assume the following:

n: no. of characters n>=1
r: no. of characters in a combination string [if n=4, r=4: cbc,cdc...(assumed characters in n{a,b,c,d}]

n=3 [assume a,b,c]
r=4

Now i have to generate the combinations which must have:

1. It must not start and end with 'a' (the first character in the assumed set).
2. The combinations can contain repetitions of same character but not at adjacent positions (e.g. bcc, bbc are invalid strings, while bac, bcb, cab, cbc.. are valid strings)
3. characters in the string can be repeated but same string must not be repeated

> possible output of above scenario: bcb, bac, cbc, cab, cac, bab

Also if n=3 and r=5
output will be: babc bcbc.. (r-1 characters in a string)

Help me with the calculation part how to find no. of such combinations based on above criteria.

Comment: Please clarify "it must not start and end with 'a'". Do you mean "it must neither start nor end with 'a'", or "it must not be of the form 'a…a'"? Your two sample outputs differ in this respect.

Comment: @PatrickStevens If you assumed a,b,c then it must not start and end with the first character in the set. e.g. aba, aca etc are invalid.

Comment: The condition about a, what does it mean? Is a forbidden at the beginning, and also at the end? Or is it just that we must avoid the words that begin with a and simultaneously end in a?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I've updated the question to clear the doubt caused.

Comment: What is allowed is not yet clear to me. Is abc allowed in your first list?

Comment: @AndréNicolas No, abc is invalid as 'a' can't be at first/last place. although 'a' can appear in middle. and regarding r-1 thing, if r=6 then string can be bcabc, cabac, cbcbc.. etc i.e. the string will contain 5 characters

Comment: Then why is bcba allowed in the length $4$ strings?

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's the condition, the first character from the assumed set can't be there in the string at first/last position.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The 'bcba' was entered by mistake, I've corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

First we count the interior of the string (the string of characters between the first and last characters):

$$ \binom{n}{r-3}.$$

There are $n-1$ choices for each of the first and last terms so we have:

$$\binom{n}{r-3}\cdot(n-1)^2.$$

Comment: Can you please explain a little more, I'm trying but not able to get you